# Selection by location: select what is at the left of another layer

Tags: qgis, layers, select-by-location

I would like to know if there is a way to select the part of a layer that is located at the left (or at the west) of another layer. I thought it would work with select by location, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please add a picture of the layers. Such task can range from very simple to extremely hard depending on the complexity of the shape(s)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the requested task using not *Select by location* but *Select by expression*.

In the image below you can see one example of the necessary expression that selects all the features that have an X coordinate smaller than the `X_min` (minimum X coordinate) of the polygon.

This selects all the features on the left side. 
This is the expression:

```
--features on the left
 $x < x_min(geometry(get_feature('polygon','id',1) ))
```

If you want to select all the feature on the right side just change the symbol `<` with `>` and `x_min` with `x_max`.

[image]

**NB:** This expression work with points. If you want to select lines or polygons, using the same expression, the X coordinate of the selectable layer will be the centroid of the geometry.

To change from the X centroid to the extreme coordinate, you must change the `$X` with `x_min($geometry)` or `x_min($geometry)` according to the side you want to select.

Example with lines:

```
  x_max($geometry) < x_min(geometry(get_feature('polygon','id',1) ))
```

Comment: Oh thanks ! I will try this !

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please vote it. This help other people to understand if the answer offers a good solution.